# AWS AppSync Schema - Arrays of Connections Both Directions

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

My issue is that I need to have a connection between two schema models where each links to an array of the other. The scenario here is I have multiple `Location`, each `Location` has multiple `Staff`. Each `Staff` can also have multiple `Location` that they are authorized at.

I don't see a way to do this in the documentation. Originally I have each `Location` with multiple `Staff`, but this limits each `Staff` to 1 `Location`. I'm toying with the idea of `altLocationNames` as an array of strings with each `Staff`, but this would require me to perform an extra query of all `Staff` or all `Locations` if the `altLocationNames` is needed.

Does anybody know a clever way to do this, or even just the best way for me to get all `Staff` at `Location` as well as all `Locations` for a specific `Staff`?

Schemas:

```
type Staff
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: iam }, { allow: private, provider: userPools }])
  @key(fields: ["email"])
  @key(name: "byId", fields: ["id"], queryField: "listStaffsById")
  @key(name: "byLocation", fields: ["locationName", "recordedAt"], queryField: "listStaffsByLocation")
  @key(name: "byRole", fields: ["role", "recordedAt"], queryField: "listStaffsByRole")
  @key(name: "byStatus", fields: ["status", "recordedAt"], queryField: "listStaffsByStatus") {
  email: AWSEmail!
  altEmails: [AWSEmail]
  id: ID!
  locationName: String!
  location: Location @connection(fields: ["locationName"])
  altLocationNames: [String]
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  role: StaffRole
  status: StaffStatus
  recordedAt: AWSDateTime!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
}

type Location
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: iam }, { allow: private, provider: userPools }])
  @key(fields: ["name"]) {
  name: String!
  subdomain: String
  address: String
  phone: String
  email: AWSEmail
  staff: [Staff] @connection(keyName: "byLocation", fields: ["name"])
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your question relates to Amplify directives, rather than the underlying AppSync.  I added the [aws-amplify] tag to the question.

Comment: I don't believe this is Amplify specific, actually more GraphQL than AWS but I've only used GQL with AppSync, so I'm not sure if there's a syntax difference here.

Comment: `@connection`, `@model`, `@key`, and `@auth` are [Amplify-only directives](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/directives/). Amplify uses them to build your DynamoDB table(s) and your AppSync GraphQL schema / resolvers.  These directives do not exist in AppSync, where you write your own resolvers.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for clarifying. I need to go back and learn the graphql basics once my to-do list gets shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create middle table between location and staff table and fetch via that table.
Example:

```
type Staff
  @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  locations: [StaffLocation] @connection(keyName: "staffLocationByStaffId", fields: ["id"])
}
type Location
  @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  staffs: [StaffLocation] @connection(keyName: "staffLocationByLocationId", fields: ["id"])
}
type StaffLocation
  @key(name: "staffLocationByStaffId", fields: ["staffId"])
  @key(name: "staffLocationByLocationId", fields: ["locationId"])
  @model {
  id: ID!
  staffId: ID!
  locationId: ID!
  staff: Staff @connection(fields: ["staffId"])
  location: Location @connection(fields: ["locationId"])
}
```

Comment: Let's make sure I understand this. StaffLocation would basically be a table of unique staff and location combinations. Example: James/Seattle, James/Portland, John/Seattle, John/Atlanta. If I query list by Staff James, I would get both J/S and J/P and their connections. If I query list by Location Seattle, I would get both J/S and J/S. 

I think this may be the only workaround, although requires data duplication. This scenario of Staff and Location should be relatively small amounts of data at least. This would also require regular sync of the Staff and Location tables into StaffLocation